# Remote Desktop Connection: "This computer can't connect to the remote computer"

Tags: rdc

I'm unable to connect remotely to one of a number of servers on the network running 2012 R2 using the Windows RDC client.

**Here is the error:**

[image]

**So far I've done the following:**

- Ping the server in question. Connectivity = fine.
- Checked Remote Desktop is enabled (system properties > remote > allow remote connections to this computer)
- Windows firewall is currently turned OFF for all profiles (domain, private, public)
- telnet from another machine on the network to the server on port 3389: I just get a blank cursor, no connection
- run *netstat -o -a* to check the server is listening on port 3389. It is, see below:

TCP      0.0.0.0:3389     servername:0      LISTENING       3236

- I have also run qwinsta to check the RDC service is listening, see pic below:

[image]

- I have rebooted the server, checked firewall on the client (and tested from multiple clients)
- Nothing in event logs
- I have changed the listening port (regedit > hklm\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp port) and done all of the above, same happens. netstat shows the node is listening on 3390 but can't connect by RDC client or telnet on that new port.

I followed [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2477023) unusually thorough article on support.microsoft.com (despite it seems to refer to Server 2003) to troubleshoot further.

I'm concluding that I should somehow find a way to blat the RDC service and rebuild it. Is that possible?

Comment: The registry key should be named "PortNumber" not "port". And it should be set to 0x00000d3d (3389). When I inherited my network, the previous owners had changed all the port numbers because they didn't want anyone using remote desktop. Took me a while to figure it out.

Comment: I'm always a fan of changing the default port numbers, depending on how open the server may be to the outside world. Yes, I meant PortNumber - that key is set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, here is my solution:

It actually happens to be a problem with the security layer negotiation between the RDP-Host and RDP-Client.
Long story short, I had to manipulate a RDP-file on text level and had to change the following value:

negotiate security layer:i:0

Give it a try, maybe it helps you aswell

Comment: " I had to manipulate a RDP-file on text level" This is not very helpful. What file, what path? I assume you mean the RDP file for the client (C:\Users\<yourUsername>\Documents\Default.rdp). This does not seem like a good solution, that means anyone that wants to connect to this host needs to adjust that setting. That setting is there for a reason, your disabling negotiation. Don't do this. We're having the same issue, out of troubleshooting sake I tried changing this setting. It did not help, same problem.